# How to wait after setting the state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**React 16.8 (Using classes not hooks)**

consider the following `if` statement in a function thats called `onClick`

```
 if (this.state.opponentIsDead) {
    this.setState({
      disableAttack: 'disabled',
    }, () => {
      this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.props.postFightData({
          train_exp: 100,
          drop_chance: this.state.monster.drop_chance,
          gold_rush_chance: this.state.monster.gold_rush_chance,
          gold_drop: this.state.monster.gold_drop,
        });
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
```

What I am trying to do is wait a second before posting the fight data if you have won the fight, the time out piece works. But as you can see I am updating the state to disable the button.

What I was thinking of doing is moving the timeout to the `componentDidUpdate` method, that way the component will re-render and the button will be disabled, how ever I feel thats the wrong way to do it.

I understand you can wrap the `setState` in an async function, but I also wonder if thats the best approach.

**The goal is to disable the button, then wait 1 second and post the data. Whats the best approach?**

### Whats wrong with this approach?

For those who might not know, the `setState` will be called to update the state, but instead of re-rendering it will then call the callback function thus the button is not disabled while the timer counts down.

it will be disabled after the timer, not before, where as I want it before, not after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect something else is causing you issue. This code seems to be working the way you want (or I'm misunderstanding).

https://codesandbox.io/s/8nz508y96j - button click disables the button and post alert appears 3 seconds later

Though using `componentDidUpdate` is the recommended approach..

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

> The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered. Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for such logic instead.

Comment: So you suggest to move my waiting for a post to the componentDidUpdate? Wouldn’t that be bad because your polluting it with logic when it should just set the state if the previous state and or props didn’t match the new stuff?

Comment: I was really just relaying the doc recommendation tbh. I think that recommendation is based on it being better that your component bases it's behaviour on it's state. In this case it would require more logic and tracking of state as you say (did they click, has the request been fired, etc). I'd be inclined to leave it as is until you find a reason to change it.

Answer (score -5):

This should do it.

```
if (this.state.opponentIsDead) {
  this.setState({
    disableAttack: 'disabled',
  });

  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.postFightData({
        train_exp: 100,
        drop_chance: this.state.monster.drop_chance,
        gold_rush_chance: this.state.monster.gold_rush_chance,
        gold_drop: this.state.monster.gold_drop,
      });
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

Comment: Would love to have an explanation as to why this is preferred over the other solutions. The author asks what the best solution would be. While your solution works, i don't know if its the 'best' way to do it. If your running react fiber, there is a chance the timer could be fired before a state update.

Comment: @pkfire can you explain how this works? Why does this work?

Comment: @MathewKleppin That actually doesn't work. the disableAttack is still not set